# CSV Result is printing more then one time

Tags: java, restlet

I am using csvwriter to get the output in csv format in java .

I have a procedure which is returning data in following format:

```
  result  didNumber     businessName  actualNumber    
          91930921800  TEMP NAME  
          917930921800 TEMP NAME  
 NOANSWER 917930921800 TEMP NAME  9845618737
 NOANSWER 917930921800 TEMP NAME  9845618737
 NOANSWER 917930921800 TEMP NAME  8951577970
 NOANSWER 917930921801 TEMP NAME  9920036823
 NOANSWER 917930921802 TEMP NAME  8762224646
 NOANSWER 917930921802 TEMP NAME  9845618737
 NOANSWER 917930921803 TEMP NAME  9448017755
 NOANSWER 917930921803 TEMP NAME  9845618737
 NOANSWER 917930921895 TEMP NAME  9448017755
DIALING 917930921800 TEMP NAME  8951577970
DIALING 917930921802 TEMP NAME  8762224646
```

Here is my java code to write in csv file.

```
 public void writeCSVData(ResultSet cdrs,String fileName) throws IOException, SQLException {
  String methodName = "writeCSVData";
  logger.debug("entering in " + methodName + " in " + className);
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(createFile(fileName).getAbsoluteFile()));
  CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer);
  String currentDid = null;
  String prevDid = null;
  String businessName = null;
  String businessReference = null;
  String actualNumber = null;
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     String[] entries = null;
     int count = 0;
  while (cdrs.next()) {              
   currentDid = cdrs.getString("didNumber");
   if (count == 0){
    prevDid = currentDid;
    result.append(currentDid);
    result.append(",");
    businessName = cdrs.getString("businessName");
    result.append(businessName);
       result.append(",");
    businessReference = cdrs.getString("businessReference");
    result.append(businessReference);
       result.append(",");
       actualNumber = cdrs.getString("actualNumber");
    result.append(actualNumber);
    count++;
    continue;
   }
     if(!prevDid.equals(currentDid)){
    entries = result.toString().split(",");
       result.append("\n");
    csvWriter.writeNext(entries);
    prevDid = currentDid;
    currentDid = cdrs.getString("didNumber");
    result.append(currentDid);
       result.append(",");
    businessName = cdrs.getString("businessName");
    result.append(businessName);
       result.append(",");
    businessReference = cdrs.getString("businessReference");
    result.append(businessReference);
       result.append(",");
    actualNumber = cdrs.getString("actualNumber");
    result.append(actualNumber);
       result.append(",");
    continue;
   }
      if(prevDid.equals(currentDid)){
    prevDid = currentDid;
    result.append(",");
    actualNumber = cdrs.getString("actualNumber");
    result.append(actualNumber);
       result.append(",");
    continue; 
      }


  }
 }
```

Basically I am writing all the actual number for a `didNumber` in one line and I am writing it to csv.

The response is correct only the thing is every line is repeating more than once .

Here is my output:

```
"917930921800","TEMP NAME","null","null","null","","9845618737","","8951577970","","9845618737","","8951577970"
"917930921800","TEMP NAME","null","null","null","","9845618737","","8951577970","","9845618737","","8951577970","
917930921801","TEMP NAME","null","9920036823"
"917930921800","TEMP NAME","null","null","null","","9845618737","","8951577970","","9845618737","","8951577970","
917930921801","TEMP NAME","null","9920036823","
917930921802","TEMP NAME","null","8762224646","","8762224646","","9845618737"
"917930921800","TEMP NAME","null","null","null","","9845618737","","8951577970","","9845618737","","8951577970","
917930921801","TEMP NAME","null","9920036823","
917930921802","TEMP NAME","null","8762224646","","8762224646","","9845618737","
917930921803","TEMP NAME","null","9448017755","","9845618737
```

Ideally the response should be like this:

```
 "917930921800","TEMP NAME","null","null","null","","9845618737","","8951577970","","9845618737","","8951577970"
    917930921801","TEMP NAME","null","9920036823","
    917930921802","TEMP NAME","null","8762224646","","8762224646","","9845618737"
    917930921803","TEMP NAME","null","9448017755","","9845618737
```

Please show me what might I have done wrong.

Comment: If you want help, try to isolate the problem and make the code cleaner. At least remove debugging instructions, they don't help us at all..

Comment: Use a CSV library like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend  you to use some library like opecsv as Lutz suggested .

The possible problem is here .

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```

Yoou are declearing this line outside the loop and not reseting it after the writing the string .

Add the following line below `csvWriter.writeNext(entries);`

```
result.delete(0, result.length());
```

It will reset the string .